# Clickable GridViewRow overriding child HyperLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

So I made each row of a GridView clickable using this method:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["OnClick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString());
    }
}
```

So that when I click a row, the program redirects to Page1 via the GridView.SelectedRowChanged method.

Each row also contains some a HyperLink that is supposed to redirect to Page2.  However, clicking on the HyperLink only redirects to Page1 because the SelectedRowChanged event fires first.

How do I redirect to the correct page when the HyperLink is clicked?  Is it as simple as making the HyperLinks LinkButtons and executing the Click method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is as easy as making the HyperLinks LinkButtons and executing the Click method.  Who knew?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the target control is an anchor, ignore postback execution. Check the following instance.

```
<div onclick="if(event.target.tagName != 'A') { alert('Foo'); }" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
</div>
```